# Creating a pulldown on website using values from php variable?

Tags: javascript, createelement

I am creating a form that the user can add more fields to their form if they need them for data.

I am using a javascript function which is triggered by a action button that creates a row of textboxes and one pull down field.

However in that row I need a pull down with the options "Yes and No", I already have them in a php array variable called $success

This is what I have to try and create a pull down but its not working.

```
ta[n]=document.createElement('option');
ta[n].value = <?php echo $success; ?>;
ta[n].name='success'+n;
```

Could someone help me out thanks for your time :)

This is the bulk of the current code

```
if(inp[c].value=='add') 
    {
       inp[c].onclick=function() 
        {
           ta[n]=document.createElement('input');
           ta[n].setAttribute('rows',1);
           ta[n].setAttribute('cols',20);
           ta[n].name='time'+n;
           document.getElementById('txtara').appendChild(ta[n])
           ta[n]=document.createElement('input');
           ta[n].setAttribute('rows',1);
           ta[n].setAttribute('cols',20);
           ta[n].name='event'+n;
           document.getElementById('txtara').appendChild(ta[n])
           ta[n]=document.createElement('input');
           ta[n].setAttribute('rows',1);
           ta[n].setAttribute('cols',20);
           ta[n].name='supplies'+n;
           document.getElementById('txtara').appendChild(ta[n])
          var sel = document.createElement('select');
```

Comment: I would like to point out this is not creating a "pulldown" just a textbox

Comment: can you post ur complete code in http://jsfiddle.net because i have no idea where all your variables come from..

Answer (score 0):

Here you go (i think this is what you wanted to do):

http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/4brz2/

```
var sel = document.createElement('select');

var ta = [];
var n = 0;

ta[n]=document.createElement('option');
ta[n].value = 'YES';
ta[n].name='success'+n;
ta[n].innerHTML = ta[n].value;
n++;
ta[n]=document.createElement('option');
ta[n].value = 'NO';
ta[n].name='success'+n;
ta[n].innerHTML = ta[n].value;
n++;

sel.appendChild(ta[0]);
sel.appendChild(ta[1]);


document.getElementById('here').appendChild(sel);
```

Comment: Thanks how do I include this with the rest of my code

[code]

Comment: just put it in script tags. i have no idea what ur code looks like... also it might be even easier to create the select dropdown with plain ol' html

Comment: Not a fan of the inconsistent use of semicolons.

Comment: I have added the other bit of code im using with this function,